# Does there exist $C$ such that $|\sin x-x| \leq C|x^3|,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Which of the following is correct:
>
> I. $\exists C (\log(x)\leq C\sqrt{x},\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+)$
>
> II. $\exists C (\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \leq Cn^2,\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+)$
>
> III. $\exists C (|\sin x-x| \leq C|x^3|,\forall x \in \mathbb{R})$

First, (I) is true since $\log(x)<\sqrt{x}$ for all $x>0$.

Then I think (II) is false. $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 =\frac{n(n+1)(2n+2)}{6}$ and it has order $3$ and $O(n^3)>O(n^2)$.

I have no idea about (III).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (III), recall that $x$ is one of the Maclaurin polynomials for $\sin(x)$. Specifically, it is the Maclaurin polynomial of degree at most $2$ (because $\sin''(0)=0$). Apply the Lagrange remainder formula for this degree, and then recall that all derivatives of $\sin$ are uniformly bounded on the whole line.

Comment: I find that $\sin(x)-x=\frac{-\cos(c)x^2}{2!}$ where $0<c<x$ and hence (III) is true?

Comment: @SHBaoS You made a mistake: for the polynomial of degree at most $2$ the error term should involve $x^3$.

Comment: Since $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$, then $x$ is the polynomial of degree $1$. Then $\sin(x)-x =\frac{f^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$. Since $x$ is of degree $1$, then $n=1$. Why $x$ is the polynomial of degree at most $2$? Could $x$ be the polynomial of degree $2$?

Comment: @SHBaoS It is indeed the polynomial of degree $1$; from this perspective the Lagrange remainder gives you $\sin(x)-x=-\sin(c)\frac{x^2}{2}$. However, $\sin''(0)=-\sin(0)=0$. Therefore $x$ is also the Maclaurin polynomial of degree at most $2$: $0+x+0 \cdot x^2/2=x$. So you also get a Lagrange remainder involving $x^3$. (This is just one way to do it, there are a few others that come to mind.)